# Как выполнить clone и append один раз в setinterval

Tags: javascript, jquery, append, clone

Есть код, который добавляет элемент в карточку товара, но загвостка в том, что он начинает много раз клонировать эти объекты

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
function appendToCart() {
    if ($('.t-store__card[data-product-uid="107483897854"]').is('.pizza-option-cart')) {
        return false;
    } else {
        $('.pizza-option-cart').clone().prependTo('[data-product-uid="107483897854"] 
.js-product-controls-wrapper');
        return false;
    }
};
function CheckCartPizza() {
    if($('*').is('.t-store__card[data-product-uid="107483897854"]')) {
        setInterval(appendToCart, 1000);
    }
};
setInterval(CheckCartPizza, 1000);
});
</script>
```

Нужно один раз добавить элемент **pizza-option-cart** и он постоянно должен проверятся, такие к сожалению особенности (из за динамически подгружаемого контента). Помогите с решением.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if ($('[data-product-uid="107483897854"] .js-product-controls-wrapper').find('.pizza-option-cart').length == 0) {
  ...
}
```